# Want to build tex file but Recipe terminated with error

Tags: texlive, compiling, latexmk, vscode, latex-workshop

error message :

```
The command name is D:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\mktexfmt
Latexmk: fls file doesn't appear to have been made.
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'Latex_Text_Template1.log' for details
----------------------
This message may duplicate earlier message.
Latexmk: Failure in processing file 'd:/ys_/study/custom_setup/workplaces/issues-in-computer-programming-20210818/Latex_Text_Template1':
   *LaTeX didn't generate the expected log file 'Latex_Text_Template1.log'
----------------------
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
D:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 12:
perl.exe d:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -pdf -outdir={my path} {tex file path}
```

OS : windows 10
File was operated in vscode
I installed latex-workshop and installed texlive.
I don't know why building tex file failed.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This is the sort of question best sent to tex-live@tug.org  Be specific about what hardware and OS you are using, and include the error messages you get.  (The report you show here would be good.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton looks like an error in a tex document not a structural error in the distribution so tex-live list probably not the right place.

Comment: all the messages you show just say that you got a tex error that is logged in `Latex_Text_Template1.log` but you have not shown eiher that log with the error or your tex source that had the error